# xslt assign a path to a variable and call the variable later on

Tags: xml, xslt

I am fairly new to XSLT and I am having trouble assigning a path to a variable.

Say i have the following example xml......

```
<CINEMA>
    <FILMS>
       <FILM_NAME>SomeFilmName</FILM_NAME>
       <FILM_NAME>SomeOtherFilmName</FILM_NAME>
    </FILMS>
</CINEMA>
```

And i declare the following variable....

```
<xsl:variable name="POS1" select="child::FILMS/descendant::FILM_NAME[1][. = 'SomeFilmName']"/>
```

If i call the variable using the following test I recieve no result as it appears it in not evaluating correctly

```
<xsl:template match="CINEMA">
<xsl:if test="$POS1">
.....Do some processing here if the above test evaluates to true........
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

However if i specify the actual path in the test without the call to a variable it seems to evaluate correctly.

Can anyone explain if what i want is possible please? If so, can anyone identify what is wrong when using the variable.

Thanks in advance, any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample of the XSLT code that allows others to reproduce the problem. Whether that variable selects anything depends on the context, you have not shown any for that `xsl:variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that variable is a global one then you need to use an absolute path `<xsl:variable name="POS1" select="/CINEMA/FILMS/descendant::FILM_NAME[1][. = 'SomeFilmName']"/>` or one relative to the root node `<xsl:variable name="POS1" select="CINEMA/FILMS/descendant::FILM_NAME[1][. = 'SomeFilmName']"/>`.

Your current attempt only makes sense if the context node is the `CINEMA` element, as in

```
<xsl:template match="CINEMA">
<xsl:variable name="POS1" select="child::FILMS/descendant::FILM_NAME[1][. = 'SomeFilmName']"/>
<xsl:if test="$POS1">
.....Do some processing here if the above test evaluates to true........
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course in that case it might be easier to simply put a predicate on the match pattern

```
<xsl:template match="CINEMA[FILMS/descendant::FILM_NAME[1][. = 'SomeFilmName']]">
.....Do some processing here if the above test evaluates to true........
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Honnen, you have made my day :) this was for a global variable so changing the path defined in the variable to an absolute made the difference. I can see what you mean now considering in my original attempt the path was never going to find the FILM_NAME descendant as the context was not CINEMA.